# Why my BRAND NEW Lenovo T590 (and before Ideapad flex 5) dies when it still has some battery left?

Tags: battery, thinkpad

I don't know if it is just my magnificent bad luck or the quality of Lenovo is deteriorating. I had to buy a number of ideapad flex 5 before landing on one without a plethora of problems. Turns out just two weeks later the battery malfunctioned where when it reaches 25%, it dies. I had to plug the pc in and found out it was charging from 0%.

I was done with lenovo at that point and considered dell. But then I realized literally everyone is using thinkpad, which is from the notorious lenovo, in the software industry. So I bought a thinkpad t590. First one, some apps wouldn't even display. The second one seemed promising. But literally as with the ideapad, after two weeks, the battery malfunctioned. When it reaches 10%, it dies. Plug it back in and it charges from 0%. Oh, and did I mention hibernate doesn't work?

I am so frustrated why I have to live with this bad luck. Not a single review on either pc mentioned a single simple problem. If there were any, it was very specific. But, these laptops have all of the simplest problems!

Please someone help me lessen my miseries. Why does my laptop not complete a full charge cycle? Literally everyone has problems with their pc a good year or so after their purchase, but only TWO WEEKS have passed and so many problems. fml

Comment: We have hundreds of Lenovo computers at clients and businesses.  No major trouble as you report. I would certainly report each case with Lenovo Support and ask them. My X230 is 8 years old, 2nd battery it that time, running Windows Insider very well. My X1 (here) is 4 years old and is excellent. My ThinkCenter M73 Desktop runs 7x24 and is trouble free. Do get Lenovo to help you.

Comment: Oh yes they will, but u hafta be rich and shower them with money to get the simplest answers

Comment: Not if the machines are new as you say. Support for the first year (maybe beyond) is free, warranty support. Not a dime needed.

Comment: software support is under the one year free warranty, not hardware. they said battery issues are hardware issues and i have to pay extra

Comment: Are you certain you purchased new from Lenovo (not refurbished from a third party). All (Thnkpads at least) come with a basic 1 year warranty including the battery. I am not certain about Ideapads but I think they are covered.  https://support.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/ht505088-product-warranty-and-other-agreements

Comment: I bought it from amazon, but it doesn't say refurbished anywhere on the site. The battery thing is their words - battery isn't included in the software warranty

Comment: There may be an issue with the vendor. I purchase from Lenovo (direct for me, bona fide partner for clients) and the warranty is as I describe. You may have a bone to pick with the vendor.

Comment: i got my ideapads from costco. Is costco a bad vendor too? >:(

Comment: Costco and Amazon are retailers. They would buy from a third party Lenovo reseller. They would be guided by consumer complaints to determine the value of their relationship. I meant that Lenovo reseller when I said Vendor. Amazon is usually transparent about their vendors. I have not purchased computers from Costco.